# Install of Raspbian Jessie does not work

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie

When I tried to install Raspbian Jessie, on the first boot my Raspberry Pi 2 got stuck on:

["A start job is running for LSB: Set console font and keymap"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6jNQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi SE Community.  I do agree that looks as though something is not going according to plan - my first install was done blind (my "Second User" Pi has a faulty HDMI output) and I do recall it took ages as the NOOBS/Raspbian setup does need to juggle things around on the SD card on the first occasion (resizing partitions); that doesn't *seem* to be the case for you, so let's see if someone else can point you in the right direction...

Comment: So the problem is from my SD card ( TDK 8Go class10 ) ? ( when i try to use NOOBS 1.5, it crashed before i can select a OS to install )

Comment: That *sounds* as though it ought to be an Ok card - there is a list somewhere of good/bad ones - use the search box in the top right of the screen to see if you can find it.  I'd wonder more about the Power Supply - and what peripherals that are plugged into the Pi's four own USB ports (NOT plugged into a Powered HUB attached to one of those four) the power that *those* four can supply to USB devices is a bit limited.

Comment: In fact, Raspbian Wheezy ( 2015-05-05 ) work, but when i do apt-get update/upgrade and reboot the rpi, it crash on boot. Are there a way to skip a step in boot of raspbian ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to a list of SD card's.

http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth I had this exact same problem. I tried swapping all peripherals, two different Pi 2 Model B's, different power supplies and two different cards. These combinations had all worked fine with Wheezy but didn't play ball when it came to running Jessie - both an upgraded version and a clean downloaded image.

[image: Boot Screen]

I came across this post and although I had tried two different cards they were both the same make/model (Delkin Micro SDHC 8GB class 10). I also noticed that the green ACT LED stayed on solidly once the boot process hung. So the final thing I tried was swapping in a third SD card from a different manufacturer - an  SanDisk Ultra I had previously used for a GoPro. This booted up first time! It would therefore seem that the newer Raspbian images are much more sensitive to the type of card used.